# Symfony2. Enum: pls explain "You can register this type with Type::addType('enumvisibility', 'MyProject\DBAL\EnumVisibilityType')"

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, enums

I am trying to implemt the following [instruction](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook/mysql-enums.html), as to have Enum type somehow

Shame on me, but I have not an idea on how/where I go to "register [the defined] type with `Type::addType('<enummyfield>', 'MyProject\DBAL\<EnumMyfield>Type')`".

EDIT Answer 1 helps. It seems I need too:

- to move definition of EnumMyfield to directory `MyBundle\Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type` (with appropriate `use` declarations)
- to update app\config\config.yml with lines

  `types:
    <myfield>: <mybundle>\Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type\<EnumMyfield>Type`
- since I wish to have a Select on the Form side, to define: 
  `->add('MyField','choice', array('label'=>'Select please', 'choices'=>array('A'=>'A','B'=>'B'))`, within my `MyentityType\buildForm()`.

With respect to the last point, if I just use `choices'=>array('A','B')`, values for the select options are rendered as numbers (0,1), and I run into an error (I am not sure why)

your comments/advises are welcome

Comment: Could you give us custom type definition?

Answer (score 0):

Just a recap, useful for others (maybe); I will highlight were you're blocked

1. Create a directory `Doctrine\DBAL\Types`
2. Define your new DBAL type there like shown into your [link](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook/mysql-enums.html)
3. **Register it into your bundle main file** (*) <--- this is what you're missing
4. Use it into entity definition

(*) You have a file inside your bundle named `YourBundleNameBundle.php` this file is used to register the bundle. If you want to register your custom type also, put inside this bundle the string `Type::addType('enum', 'MyProject\DBAL\EnumType')".`

So, something like

```
public function boot()
{
    if (false === Type:hasType('enum')) {
        $em = $this->container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
        Type::addType('enum', 'Path\To\Bundle\Doctrine\DBAL\Types\EnumType');
        $em->getConnection()->getDatabasePlatform()->registerDoctrineTypeMapping('enum','enum');   
    }     
}
```

Don't forget the `use` statement

```
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type;
```

at the top of the file

Comment: instead of your boot(), it seems enough to register within config.yml, see my edit.

Comment: @mario: yes, this could be enough. I prefer to keep it along my bundle as, if I need it only in there, or if I need to share my bundle, no additional work has to be done.